# PostgreSQL error: converted to the required encoding

Tags: postgresql, encoding, pgadmin

I am trying to update a column:

```sql
update t_references
set    reference = 'St&#246;cker W, et al. Autoimmunity to Pancreatic Juice in Crohn&#8217;s Disease. 
    Results of an Autoantibody Screening in Patients With Chronic Inﬂammatory Bowel Disease. <i>Scand J Gastroenterol Suppl</i>. 1987;139:41-52.'
      ,index = 9
where  reference_id = 161;
```

I got error:

> The query could not be converted to the required encoding.

Please advise.

---

I had to login to the machine and then ran this from the command.

Comment: What is the definition of the table as shown by the `psql`'s `\d` command?

Comment: Table definition is   pg_default

Comment: This message is produced by pgadmin, not by postgresql. Also the update statement itself seems dubious anyway: no doubling or escaping of the single quote (_Crohn's_), no WHERE clause.

Comment: Right, I have updated the scripts

Comment: As @Daniel mentioned, the error msg comes from pgAdmin. To be precise from [`pgQueryThread.cpp`](http://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=pgadmin3.git;a=blob;f=pgadmin/db/pgQueryThread.cpp;h=96532864f06bcdd0e7d0cdcb6c15169a6147b916;hb=HEAD). I have never had this error though.

Answer (score 1):

On experiencing the same error, I found I could recreate it when opening a .SQL file saved from PGAdmin in an editor(even Notepad) and then copying and pasting the contents into PGAdmin. When I opened the file directly with PGAdmin, there was no issue.

HTH